# How to use detex or opentex

Tags: detex

I'm on windows, and I cannot seem to get detex to work, when I try to write detex in cmd, it will not recognize it as a command.

Comment: detex is distributed with texlive, are you using texlive or miktex (It may be distributed with miktex, i do not know)

Comment: I am using overleaf. If that is to any help.